# Handle static requests by NodeJS app or nginx?

Tags: node.js, performance, nginx, static-files

Most NodeJS web frameworks like Express, Hapi, Koa, have out-of-the-box support for static assets, like images, stylesheets, scripts.

Though, I am thinking of moving these duties to nginx which, as I suppose will simplify Node app config and probably will lead to better performance of the app.

Should I keep these static assets inside Node app environment or should I rather serve them with a 3rd party server like nginx?

Comment: Didn't test myself, but I heard a lot that Express static performance were worse than nginx, and so a dev should put the static files in nginx whenever that doesn't confuse other devs. Will try to find some example of the claim before posting as a answer.